# Python script gives a 'D' after an EOF

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a simple Python3 program like below:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
print(a + b)
```

But after sending a 'Ctrl-D' EOF I get this:

```
$ python3 APlusB.py
5 4 
9D
```

It gives a 'D' after the answer.
But if I add 5 and 5 it doesn't:

```
$ python3 APlusB.py
5 5 
10
```

Why does it send 'D' with the first, but not the second?

Comment: If you skip the printed answer, maybe you'd see `^D`, which is promptly overwritten?

Answer (score 3):

This is an artifact of your terminal.

Change your code to this:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])

import time             # add these 2 lines
time.sleep(4)

print(a + b)
```

And you will see what happens:

First, you press control-D, and the terminal shows ^D on the screen.

Then a delay occurs.

Finally, python's `print` emits 1 or 2 letters (depending on your input), which overwrite the '^D' that the terminal displayed when you pressed Ctrl-D.

I'd suggest that you start using the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) function, which does a better job dealing with the user. ;-)